# INSERT if not exists ELSE DELETE - Using ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very simple table structure in my database:

```
ID (Unique), userid, groupid
```

With a UNIQUE key on userid and groupid - so you cant have two the same. For example:

```
ID    userid    groupid
1     86        5
2     86        6
```

is possible, but:

```
ID    userid    groupid
1     86        5
2     86        5
```

Isnt possible.

This all works fine. What I am trying to do is try to INSERT the row, and if that fails due to a duplicate, DELETE that row. My code is simply:

```
$group_query = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO users_groups (userid,groupid) VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY DELETE FROM users_groups WHERE userid=? AND groupid=?");
$group_query->bind_param("iiii", $user_id, $group_id, $user_id, $group_id);
```

I dont see any reason why this shouldnt work. All of the variables are set to integers. They are all actual numbers (checked). The syntax all looks fine. The only conclusion I have is that it isnt a valid query - but I am not sure why it isnt a valid query.

Thanks for anything!

Comment: never heard of IODKD. You don't just fill in the verb of your choice.

Comment: I just ran a search on this page for IODKD and came up only with what you wrote. I have also never heard of IODKD :)

Comment: I have also never heard of IODKEMCF (insert on duplicate key email me csv file)

Comment: I havent heard of that one either! SNAP! I didn't think it was filling in the 'verb of my choice'. It was using an actual MySQL keyword to perform a function on a specific result. Didn't realise it needed such a pointed answer. "DELETE cannot be used after an ON DUPLICATE KEY" would have been sufficient, so you know for next time! :)

Comment: If my only payment on this site is a little sense of humor on occasion, I will grasp for it :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use a select statement to select the row based on userid and groupid :

```
SELECT *FROM table where userid = '86' AND groupid = '5'
```

It will return the row if exists and then check the array if greater than 0 or not

```
if($result_array > 0){
 // use delete statement
}else{
 // user insert statement
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I was trying to avoid multiple queries but I guess it looks like the simplest solution :(

Comment: Ya it may be right solution for you as performance may be increased on server

Answer (score 0):

***posibility-1:***

Insert new row by checking same records through select statement

**Insert duplicate row**

```
INSERT INTO users_groups (userid,groupid)  SELECT * FROM (SELECT 5,86) AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT `groupid` FROM users_groups WHERE userid =5 and groupid=86);
```

> output:0 rows inserted.

**Insert actual row**

```
INSERT INTO users_groups (userid,groupid)  SELECT * FROM (SELECT 6,86) AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT `groupid` FROM users_groups WHERE userid =6 and groupid=86);
```

> output: 1 row inserted.

***posibility-2:***

insert new row through replace

```
REPLACE INTO users_groups (`userid`,`groupid`) VALUES (?,?);
```

> Note:REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in
>   the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a
>   UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

***posibility-3:***

Add Unique index for groupid,userid

```
ALTER TABLE `users_groups` ADD UNIQUE (
`userid` ,
`groupid`
);
```

it wont allow to insert new record, if you are trying to insert, it will display following error

## 1062 - Duplicate entry '86-5' for key 'groupid'